# Is it possible to make a condition for a field in QGIS using CSV

Tags: qgis, shapefile, sql, csv

I have table 1 csv and table 2 shp. There are three fields in table 1 (num, obey, code), I need to make a function that can insert the Code field into table 2, but only after finding a match with the num and obey fields.[image]

The function should search for matches in the num and obey fields and then insert the code value. But this function should work continuously even after deleting or adding new objects to table 2.

But if the Code field already has a value, then the function does not fill it anymore.

Comment: Search for joining tables

Answer (score 1):

So I understand that Table 2 already contains the `num` and `obey` fields? If so, you can just perform a Table Join using the *Join attributes by field value* from the Processing algorithm Toolbox.

A detailed, step-by-step tutorial can be found [here](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/performing_table_joins.html).

Comment: This method is not suitable, you need the Code field to be updated automatically after adding new objects

Comment: Then I'm afraid you should develop your original question further and provide more data in order to better understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: Edited the question